Extracting value from comma-delimited string in Teradata
I need the value extracted from between the 5th and 6th comma of a string. STRTOK() is skipping the positions that are empty and not counting them. For example, this returns null because there are not 6 instances of values between commas:
SELECT STRTOK('1,,,,,012345678,abcdzyz,,,,,,', ',', 6) AS extracted_value;
I have tried the popular AI sites and none of the solutions are working. Can this be done in Teradata, or should I do it in python?

Did you try INSTR with occurrence parameter set to 5, and 6 and get the middle part?

I did not, I looked up an example and tried it, got this error: SUBSTR: string subscript out of bounds. (the example had me wrap INSTR with SUBSTR)

sure, instr will give you positions of commas, and substr will extract that part. You will need to check for several conditions; the first instr returns 0, second instr returns zero, first comma pos +1 = second comma pos (empty string); in these instances you will not call substr (I don't have access to a Teradata system to write the full expression)

This should work on your sample string (strThis being your string):
SUBSTR(strThis, INSTR(strThis, ',', 1, 5) + 1, INSTR(strThis, ',', 1, 6) - INSTR(strThis, ',', 1, 5) - 1)

if your string has the 5th and the 6th commas in it; you need to check for all other conditions.

thanks, works great. I counted the commas in the field I am working with, filtered out any records with less than 6 commas, and then this works perfectly.

You can use a RegEx to extract the nth value:
-- this is an undocumented variant of regexp_substr which allows to 
-- extract a specific capture group using a 6th parameter 
regexp_substr_gpl  
  ( '1,,,,,012345678,abcdzyz,,,,,,'
   ,'([^,]*+),?+'     -- any numer of non-commas followed by an optional comma
   ,1   -- startpos
   ,6   -- this is the nth occurence
   ,'c' -- case insensitive
   ,1   -- extract first capture group <---
  ) 

